# What's the purpose of str.indexOf(var && var)?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've found in a library that I'm using this piece of code:

```
item[column.field].indexOf(columnFilters[columnId] && columnFilters[columnId]) === -1)
```

and I'm wondering what's the purpose of passing the same value twice to indexOf. Or is it just a mistake and I can correct it.

Library: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example16-row-detail.html (live http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example16-row-detail.html)

Comment: I can see `blah.indexOf(columnFilters && columnFilters[columnId]) === -1` being useful to verify that columnFilters exists before digging it to one of its properties/indices.  Maybe you have a typo of that.

Comment: @James good point

Comment: Yeah, I'm the maintainer of that project. I'll remove it, it doesn't make any sense. It is in an example, not core code, and that code is not checked as strongly as the core.

Comment: @BenMcIntyre thanks, was just wondering if it's some magic ;)

Comment: it's the nature of an open source project :-)  code is submitted from different sources and vetted to varying degrees

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frankly it almost certainly doesn't make any sense there. `columnFilters[columnId] && columnFilters[columnId]` is effectively the same as `columnFilters[columnId]` except that `columnFilters[columnId]` may get evaluated twice (if it's falsy). Unless `columnFilters` has an accessor property with the name in `columnId` that has a side effect, `&&` is completely pointless there. (If it does, it'll cause its side effect twice if the result is falsy.)

`&&` evaluates its left-hand operand and, if it's falsy, takes that value as its result; if the left-hand operand evaluates truthy, `&&` evaluates the right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. So you can see why it's pointless in this case unless it's being used for side-effects from accessors, in which case it's just...a bad idea. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is the same if you write it just once like this  `indexOf(columnFilters[columnId])`